# Empty Request body when trying to log in HandlerInterceptor

Tags: java, servlets, httprequest, servlet-filters

I'm trying to log the request body from a HttpServletRequest , I added a wrapper to do so and I still get an empty request body once I retrieve it. Please how could I get the body multiple times.

```
public class LogginHandlerInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {   
         @Override
                public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
                        throws Exception {
                    System.out.println("preHandle - " + handler);
                    MDC.put(START_TIME_VAR, Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    MultiReadHttpServletRequest requestWrapper = new MultiReadHttpServletRequest(request);

                final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                InputStream inputStream = requestWrapper.getInputStream();
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                    String line;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        builder.append(line);
                    }

                    MDC.put(REQUEST_BODY_VAR, builder.toString());
```

Wrapper:

```
public class MultiReadHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private ByteArrayOutputStream cachedBytes;

    public MultiReadHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        if (cachedBytes == null)
            cacheInputStream();

        return new CachedServletInputStream();
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getInputStream()));
    }

    private void cacheInputStream() throws IOException {
        /*
         * Cache the inputstream in order to read it multiple times. For
         * convenience, I use apache.commons IOUtils
         */
        cachedBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        IOUtils.copy(super.getInputStream(), cachedBytes);
    }

    /* An inputstream which reads the cached request body */
    public class CachedServletInputStream extends ServletInputStream {
        private ByteArrayInputStream input;

        public CachedServletInputStream() {
            /* create a new input stream from the cached request body */
            input = new ByteArrayInputStream(cachedBytes.toByteArray());
        }

        @Override
        public int read() throws IOException {
            return input.read();
        }
    }
}
```

where I do get an empty request body (rawrequest has a header but body empty):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/someuri", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody Object post(final HttpServletRequest request,
        @PathVariable final String parameter, @PathVariable final String parameter2,
        HttpEntity<String> rawrequest, @RequestHeader("Authorization") final String Authorization) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to reset the body in the request using **setAttribute**    in the Interceptor.

```
request.setAttribute("com.xp.input", body);
```

then I retreive it in my process:

```
Object body = request.getAttribute("com.xp.input");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ContentCachingRequestWrapper` instead of `MultiReadHttpServletRequest`:

```
HttpServletRequest requestCacheWrapperObject = new ContentCachingRequestWrapper(request);
requestCacheWrapperObject.getParameterMap();
// Read inputStream from requestCacheWrapperObject and log it
```

More info [here](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging).

Comment: ContentCachingRequestWrapper class only supports the following:
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Method-Type:POST
and I'm using application/json